# how to change the font size of the text on my button (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I've googled it several different ways and found nothing, any help would be appreciated!

Code snippet:

```html
<center><p><button style="height:50px;width:200px" onclick="myFunction()" id="button">Show More</button></p></center><br>
```

Comment: in the style tag you can add `;font-size: (font size)` like so: `<center><p><button style="height:50px;width:200px;font-size:20px" onclick="myFunction()" id="button">Show More</button></p></center><br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `font-size` property:

```
<center><p><button style="height:50px;width:200px;font-size:20px" onclick="myFunction()" id="button">Show More</button></p></center>
```

Comment: thank you guys so much, i will accept an answer in a few minutes, stack overflow won't let me lol, but ty guys so much, couldn't have done it without u!

Comment: Don't answer duplicates. Instead, vote to close, marking as duplicate.